# Troubles with using Gson with JSend Standard

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

My App communicates with a rest-interface which delivers responses in form of the JSend-Standard(http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend). In order to send requests and work with the responses i'm using retrofit and gson.

So i am sending a request and the api delivers a json that looks something like this:

```
{
     status : "success",
     data :  // some json object or just a single value 
}


{
     status : "error",
     message : "Unable to communicate with database"
     code: 5
}
```

In my POJO im using a generic type to differ between the different "data" possibilities:

```
public class MyPOJO<Data>
{
    private String status;
    private Data data;
    private int code;
    private String message;
}
```

Everything is working fine so far! 
But JSend can also deliver a response in this form:

```
{
    status : "fail",
    data : { 
             title : "A title is required",
             someValue: "Also this value is required "
           }
}
```

And that's where the trouble starts.
If i get the Status "success" its fine because i exactly know what to expect and i can define the generic Type for MyPOJO (Its simply another POJO or a Boolean or whatever).

But with the status "fail" i can't really tell in advance whats inside the "data". It's mostly just a key-value listing of what went wrong, but since i don't know the keys i can't define the POJO right and i'm return an instance of MyPOJO with all its fields set to null.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve or work around this issue.
Thanks in advance!
Kind Regards

Comment: just an idea... i'd put in JSend specification but it seems to not be contamplated... why don't you put in your data POJO a status code (also HTTP Status code) so by checking the http statud code you can understand if it's a server error, a validation errro ad so on.. But i repeat it would be better in the JSend obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value of "data" in the response JSON can be null, or an object your best bet might be to just use a generic type of Map<String, Object>

Otherwise, since data can represent arbitrary errors or your expected response object you'd have to account for all the possible error key/value combinations that could be returned from any of your end points.

Comment: Thats mostly how i solved it now.
Got all the possibles keys and extended my pojos with them. An ugly solution tho IMHO. 
Thanks for your answer!